# Second Derivative test for trigo $f(x,y) = \cos x\cos y$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Q:**

> $f(x,y) = \cos x\cos y$. Use second derivative test to find local $\min$, $\max$ and saddle points.

I know that i have to differentiate w.r.t x and y which i get $-\sin x\cos y$ and $-\cos x\sin y$.

For the critical points, are $(0,π)$, $(π,π)$, $(0,0)$, $(π,0)$ correct? Do i have to include coordinates like $(π/2, π/2)$, $(3π/2 , π/2)$ ... etc? When do i have to consider the negative critical points?

I know from $f(x,y) = \sin x\sin y$ they considered negative values. I am quite confused about this, hope someone can provide some insight and help. thanks

Comment: At the critical points, both $-\cos x\sin y=0$ and $-\sin x\cos y=0$. 
This can only happen if $\sin x = 0 =\sin y$ or $\cos x = 0 =\cos y$.
 The solutions to these equations are $(x,y)=(k\pi,m\pi)$ and $(x,y)=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}+m\pi\right)$ where $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. These are all of the critical points.

Comment: Here you have everything you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test